# IntelliJ git fetch pruned remote references

Tags: git, intellij-idea, fetch

until recently I get

```
Fetch details: Pruned obsolete remote references: origin/blabla
```

when trying to fetch new branches. I dont want these branches to be pruned, where can I change this strange behaviour? Newest IntelliJ version 13.x running.

Answer (score 1):

Since the last time you fetched data, one or more branches might have been deleted on the specified remote. The "prune" option removes any remote-tracking branches that no longer exist on the remote.

let checkout branch before fetch it.

follow [this link](http://www.git-tower.com/files/applicationHelp/pgs/Refs_Remotes_Fetch.html)

Comment: Problem is they still exist on remote if I fetch per console "git fetch" I can fetch those branches, just IntelliJ fetch prunes them.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure why the problem was by me, either somebody committed uppercase branch:
e.g. should be `bugfix/bug1`
but was committed `BugFix/bug1`
or there was 2 branches, one with upper another with lower case.
Anyway i tried to remove the branch over webstorm, it was helpful only for first update, then the error was there again.

Then i noticed the uppercase branch, and removed it over git console
`git push origin --delete BugFix/bug1`
after this the branch was really removed and no error was shown.

*info:* as git repo we used gitblit.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

### git fetch -p

It'll remove all your local branches which are remotely deleted.

Comment: No it won't, it will (before fetching), "remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote". `git fetch -P` (capital) will do as you wrote; "remove any local tags that no longer exist on the remote". See [official docs here for more information](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune).